# "'builtin_function_or_method' is not subscriptable" error when using dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a currency converter program in python with the use of dictionaries.
When using condict.values(UserOrigin-1), I am receiving an error that says "'builtin_function_or_method' is not subscriptable". What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

```
def Currency():
  condict={
    "USD": 1,
    "Euro": 1.21,
    "Yen": 0.0094,
    "UK Pound": 1.39,
    "Swiss Franc": 1.12,
  }
  UserOrigin=int(input("Write the number to indicate which is the original currency.\n1. US. Dollars\n2. Euro\n3. Yen\n4. UK Pound\n5. Swiss Franc\n"))

  UserResult=int(input("Write the number to indicate which is the currency to convert to.\n1.US. Dollars\n2. Euro\n3. Yen\n4. UK Pound\n5. Swiss Franc\n"))

  UserAmount=int(input("Enter the amount:\n"))

  USDAmount=UserAmount*condict.values[UserOrigin-1]
  FinalAmount=USDAmount/condict.values[UserResult-1]
  
  print("{} {}s are {} {}s".format(UserAmount, condict.key[UserOrigin-1],FinalAmount,condict.key[UserResult-1]))


Currency()
```

Answer (score 1):

`values()` is a method of `dict` and not an attribute. You must call it with the parenthesis before any operation on the result.

Moreover, the result of `values()` is an iterator, which you cannot slice. You must transform it to a list with `list()` :

```py
USDAmount = UserAmount * list(condict.values())[UserOrigin-1]
FinalAmount = USDAmount / list(condict.values())[UserResult-1]
```

The same goes for `keys()`:

```py
print("{} {}s are {} {}s".format(UserAmount, list(condict.key())[UserOrigin-1],FinalAmount,list(condict.key())[UserResult-1]))
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the "'builtin_function_or_method' is not subscriptable" error, however now I have a new error that says "'dict_values' object is not subscriptable". What could this new error be referring to?  EDIT: The new information fixed everything. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I edited my answer, see the part about transforming the `values()` result to a list.

Comment: This fixed everything, thank you for your help! I said this in my edit in the comment, but I didn't realize I could respond to your comment.